# How to change default eclipse shell interpreter?

Tags: eclipse, bash, shell

I have installed the [`ShellEd`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/) plugin in eclipse. Whenever I run a bash script it runs it using `dash` even if I specify interpreter directive `#! /bin/bash` at the top of the script.

How do I change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THere should be an option to set the bash interpreter as follows:

```
Window->Preferences-><the_plugin_name>->Interpreter.
```

you need to set you bash interpreter path here (`/bin/bash`). 
Eclipse will use the value you set here to execute your program.

Answer (score 3):

- You need to install `Cygwin` or `MSYS/MinGW`.
- Add the interpreter `bash.exe` path in eclipse as follows:

  `Window->Preferences->Shell Script -> Interpreters`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of Eclipse current v2.23.0 and beyond the path to change terminal is:
Windows > Preferences > Shell > Local Terminal, under subtitle Show in there is a button labeled Add